# How to get the list of directories that is created after the specific time in HDFS?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I have the requirement to extract the directories that is created after a specific time period in HDFS filesystem. Did Hadoop provide any API or method to get this?

Comment: Do you want to do this in Java, or using a command line?

Answer (score 1):

If last modification time is sufficient [(Unix does not track creation times, see e.g. this post)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/24443), the following could help.

Using the API, you can ask or the [file status](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html#getFileStatus) and call [getModificationTime](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileStatus.html#getModificationTime()).

Using the commandline, you can use `hadoop fs -ls -R -t .` in Hadoop 2.7 to list all files and sort them by modification time. In previous versions, this sorting is not available. Furthermore, parsing output of `ls` is not always a good thing to do, as is explained in [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/101947).

Answer (score 1):

Sorting is the only option in previous version of Hadoop 2.7. See the example below:

```
hadoop fs -ls /tmp | sort -k6,7
```

Comment: can you elaborate ?